# Curl does not decompress the deflate page

Tags: curl, deflate

For some reason CLI version of Curl does not decompress my page even though the `Content-Encoding: deflate` header is set. Browsers open the file just fine. wget also decompresses the output. I remember it was working some time ago. What could be a reason for Curl not decompressing the deflated stream?

```
$curl app.pitchinvestorslive.com/env.js -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 401
Content-Type: text/javascript
Cache-Control: max-age=60
Content-Encoding: deflate
Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2019 14:04:17 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

�(��LY[^T����}L�s�hcyn��w͎*)��ӦԢ�L�k�x��l_c���

$ curl --version
curl 7.64.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1b zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.5 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.0.5) libssh/0.8.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.36.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2019-02-06
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

Comment: Curl requires the `--compressed` for automatic decompression, without this header it only requests uncompressed web pages.

Comment: `curl --compressed app.pitchinvestorslive.com/env.js -i` cmd  working

Answer (score 1):

Curl will automatically decompress the response if you set the --compressed flag

**--compressed**

(HTTP) Request a compressed response using one of the algorithms curl supports, and save the uncompressed document. If this option is used and the server sends an unsupported encoding, `curl` will report an error.

```
curl --compressed app.pitchinvestorslive.com/env.js -i
```